# ACTION_SET_ALARM doesn't works in Galaxy SII

Tags: android, android-intent, alarm, galaxy

I'm trying to set new alarm in the device's alarm app with `Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM)`. It works fine in all the mobiles I try it. But in Galaxy S2 it doesn't works. That intent open a empty black screen clock app, instead of alarm app.

The code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
    i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hour);
    i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, minutes);
    i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE,personalMessage);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true);
    }
    startActivity(i);
```

If I open the app directly (`com.sec.android.app.clockpackage.ClockPackage`, `setClassName`, all that stuff), I could open the correct app but doesn't set the alarm.

The code:

```
String packageName = "com.sec.android.app.clockpackage";  
    String className = "com.sec.android.app.clockpackage.ClockPackage";  
    Intent internetIntent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
    internetIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    internetIntent.setClassName(packageName, className);
    internetIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hour);
    internetIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, minutes);
    internetIntent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE,personalMessage);
    startActivity(internetIntent);
```

Anyone knows?!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried dropping `EXTRA_SKIP_UI`?

Comment: Yes, we tried it, and it still open the black scree of clock app.

Comment: Generally speaking, devices are *supposed* to honor all these `ACTION_` `Intent` actions from the SDK, but they do not have to. Ideally, they would simply not have an `<intent-filter>` for it, so we could catch the `ActivityNotFoundException` (or detect the missing activity via `PackageManager`) and deal with it. But I am not terribly shocked that this is happening, though I do not happen to have a Galaxy S2 and cannot see if I can reproduce the problem. Most likely, you will need to check for this specific device using `Build` and "route around the damage".

Comment: @CommonsWare
Sorry I don't understand this 

> Most likely, you will need to check for this specific device using Build and "route around the damage"

What do you mean?

Comment: I mean detect that you are on some device where `ACTION_SET_ALARM` does not do what you want, and do something else instead.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem.

try this:

```
private void setAlarmNow() {
    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+1;//to make sure it won't be set at the next day
    intent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
    intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hour);
    intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, minute);
    intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true);    

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);   
    Log.d(TAG, "Backup alarm geset.");
}
```